# python unittest returning strange __init__ error with requests and exception handling

Tags: python-3.x, api, python-requests, python-unittest

I have basic code that I am using to learn how to write Python unittests. It uses the "jokes" API.

The project is very simple and setup like this:

```
.
├── README.md
├── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-39.pyc
│   │   ├── calc.cpython-39.pyc
│   │   ├── joke.cpython-39.pyc
│   │   └── math.cpython-39.pyc
│   ├── calc.py
│   └── joke.py
└── test
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __pycache__
    │   ├── __init__.cpython-39.pyc
    │   └── test_joke.cpython-39.pyc
    ├── test_calc.py
    └── test_joke.py
```

the app code:

```
import requests

'''each time we make the get_joke() , we get a different result
so in order to test the len_joke(), we will mock the get_joke()
the mock will help isolate the len_joke() that is under test,
from its dependency'''

def len_joke():
  joke = get_joke()
  # add temp code for print testing during test call

  return len(joke)


def get_joke():
  url = 'http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random'

  
  try:
    response = requests.get(url, timeout=30)
    response.raise_for_status
  except requests.exceptions.Timeout:
    return "No jokes!"
  except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
    pass
  except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as e:
    status_code = e.response.status_code


    # return 'HTTP error was raised'
  else: 
    if response.status_code == 200:
      joke = response.json()['value']['joke']
    else:
      joke = "No jokes!"
  return joke
```

In order to test the application code, I have this test code:

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import MagicMock, patch
from urllib.error import HTTPError

import requests
from app import joke
from requests.exceptions import Timeout

class TestJoke(unittest.TestCase):
  '''each time we make the get_joke() , we get a different result
   so in order to test the len_joke(), we will mock the get_joke()
   the mock will help isolate the len_joke() that is under test,
   from its dependency. Our testing methodology is completely independent 
   of an external network connection or an external API'''



  @patch('app.joke.requests')
  def test_get_joke_raise_timeout_exception(self, mock_requests): 
    mock_requests.exceptions = requests.exceptions
    mock_requests.get.side_effect = Timeout('seems like the server is down')
    self.assertEqual(joke.get_joke(), 'No jokes!')
  
  # we will again need a "mock response" variable
  @patch('app.joke.requests')
  def test_get_joke_raise_for_status(self, mock_requests): 
    mock_requests.exceptions = requests.exceptions
    mock_response = MagicMock(status_code=403)
    mock_response.raise_for_status.side_effect = HTTPError('Something went wrong')
    mock_requests.get.return_value = mock_response
    self.assertEqual(joke.get_joke(), 'HTTP error was raised')
```

The application code is working and I get my joke back from the API.
The 'test_get_joke_raise_timeout_exception' test runs fine. However the 'test_get_joke_raise_for_status' is throwing the following error:

```
mock_response.raise_for_status.side_effect = HTTPError('Something went wrong')
TypeError: __init__() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'code', 'msg', 'hdrs', and 'fp'
```

Can anyone help me to interpret his traceback and figure out what's wrong with this test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HTTPError('Something went wrong')` isn't a valid way to instantiate an `HTTPError`.  The constructor of that class takes mandatory arguments `code`, `msg`, `hdrs`  and `fp`, so your test will need to supply them.

See the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5d75edd925f4e0624bd341b7c3ec8c61f0deec23/Lib/urllib/error.py#L35) and (although it isn't complete, presumably because it expects the class to be used primarily by code in the library, rather than application code) the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.error.html#urllib.error.HTTPError).